# Resizing image with php script

Tags: php, image

I am trying to resize an image that I have uploaded with a form.  I am using the script scene here:  http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

I am also using the following code to upload the image:

upload.php:

```
    <?php

    session_start();
    require_once "database.php";
    db_connect();
    require_once "auth.php";
    $current_user = current_user();

    $emailstring = $current_user['email'];

//Check to see if the type of file uploaded is a valid image type
function is_valid_type($file)
{
    //This is an array that holds all the valid image MIME types
    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");

    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
        return 1;
    return 0;   

}

function showContents($array) 
    {

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

//Set some constants

//This variable is the path to the image folder where all the images are going to be stored

//Note that there is a trailing forward slash
$TARGET_PATH = "profile_images/";

//Get our POSTed variables
$upload_picture_fileinput = $_FILES['upload_picture_fileinput'];


//Sanitize input
$upload_picture_fileinput['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($upload_picture_fileinput['name']);

//Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved to
//i.e. profile_images/picture.jpg
$TARGET_PATH .= $upload_picture_fileinput['name'];

if(!is_valid_type($upload_picture_fileinput)) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, bmp, or png";
    header("Location: account.php");
    exit;


    }

//attempt to move the file from its temporary directory to its new home
if (move_uploaded_file($upload_picture_fileinput['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH)) {

    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `profile_image_filename`='" . $upload_picture_fileinput['name'] . "'
                       WHERE email='$emailstring'";


    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());

    header("Location: account.php");
    exit;
}
else 
{


    $_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file.  Check read/write permissions on the directory";
    header("Location: account.php") ;
    exit;

    }
```

and where my form is:

```
<div class="pictures add_pictures">
            <div class="add_picture">
                <div class="upload_picture">
                    <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_picture_form" class="upload_picture_form">
                        <span class="add_picture_label">+ Add a Profile Picture</span>
                        <input type="file" name="upload_picture_fileinput" class="upload_picture_file_input"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"/>
                        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php

            $sql = "select * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$id'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());



                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


                echo "<p>";

                echo "<img src=\"profile_images/" . $row['profile_image_filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
                echo "</p>";



        ?>
                                    //not currently working
                <img src="/imageresize.php"/>
```

The echo above prints the picture out fine, but when I try to use that filename to resize the image, it does not appear/work.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once "database.php";
    db_connect();
    require_once "auth.php";
    $current_user = current_user();

    $resized_image = '\"profile_images/" . $row['profile_image_filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /';

    header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    include('SimpleImage.php');
    $image = new SimpleImage();
    $image->load($resized_image);
    $image->resizeToWidth(300);
    $image->output();


?>
```

I am connecting to the database fine and the image filename is being saved in my database.  I just don't know why the file path above will print the picture, but not work in the resize script.  Please help if you can.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in $resized_image you have added the html alt tag which should, of course, not be part of the parameter you are feeding into $image->load($resized_image);.

Try changing this to

```
$image->load('profile_images/' . $row['profile_image_filename']);
```

instead of the string that already targets the html rendering.

Comment: This still isn't returning the resized image

Comment: @MichaelSutyak which one you've changed man? i need to do the same. any changes from the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

The code below creates a function named createThumbs that will get three parameters. The first and the second is correspondingly the path to the directory that contains original images and the path to the directory in which thumbnails will be placed. The third parameter is the width you want for the thumbnail images.

```
<?php
    function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth ) 
    {
      // open the directory
      $dir = opendir( $pathToImages );

      // loop through it, looking for any/all JPG files:
      while (false !== ($fname = readdir( $dir ))) {
        // parse path for the extension
        $info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);
        // continue only if this is a JPEG image
        if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) 
        {
          echo "Creating thumbnail for {$fname} <br />";

          // load image and get image size
          $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );
          $width = imagesx( $img );
          $height = imagesy( $img );

          // calculate thumbnail size
          $new_width = $thumbWidth;
          $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

          // create a new temporary image
          $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

          // copy and resize old image into new image 
          imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );

          // save thumbnail into a file
          imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
        }
      }
      // close the directory
      closedir( $dir );
    }
    // call createThumb function and pass to it as parameters the path 
    // to the directory that contains images, the path to the directory
    // in which thumbnails will be placed and the thumbnail's width. 
    // We are assuming that the path will be a relative path working 
    // both in the filesystem, and through the web for links
    createThumbs("upload/","upload/thumbs/",100);
    ?>
```